# Understanding multiplication of Shamir secret sharing during threshold (EC)DSA signing

Tags: signature, secret-sharing, dsa, multiparty-computation, threshold-cryptography

I have been looking at the threshold (EC)DSA schemes for honest majority by Gennaro et al. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540100928815. In the scheme, there are steps where we wish to open the product of Shamir secret sharings. So for example `[a]`,`[k]` are degree-t sharings of `a`,`k` respectively, each party i holds shares `[a]_i`, `[k]_i`, and we wish to reveal the value `a*k` to all parties. The paper explains that while parties can compute `[a]*[k]` locally, this does not yield a random degree 2t-sharing of `a*k` (in particular, the polynomial underlying the sharing can not be irreducible) and so revealing `[a]_i*[k]_i` could leak information about `a` and `k`. To get around this, parties additionally hold shares of a degree-2t sharing of `0`, denoted here as `[z]`, which they add to their shares of `[a]_i*[k]_i` to re-randomize it. All parties therefore reveal their shares of `[a]_i*[k]_i + [z]_i`, from which `ak` (and the polynomial it lies on) can be interpolated.

I understand that taken by itself `[a]*[k] + [z]` is a random degree-2t polynomial with constant term `ak` and so doesn't leak any information about `a` or `k`. However, here the attacker also knows shares of `[a],[k]`, and `[z]` and what I'm struggling to understand is how to argue that `[a]*[k] + [z]` is a random sharing and doesn't leak anything conditioned on this knowledge. For example, working in a field of size `q`, if the attacker controls `t` replicas it can reduce the possibilities for the polynomials sharing `[a]`,`[k]` to sets of `q` possibilities each, and `[z]` to a set of `q^t` possibilities (since they know `t` shares of `[z]` plus point at 0). So this gives `q^(t+2)` possibilities for the polynomial underling`[a]*[k] + [z]`, which is less than the `q^2t` possibilities there would be for the polynomial underlying a random sharing of `ak`.

I know this is quite a standard trick that I've seen in other papers so I must be missing something, but I haven't been able to find a detailed proof of why this works. If anyone could help me understand the intuition behind this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand the question, my intuition is that if you're working in a field of size q, as long as the solution is constrained to a larger number of possibilities than q, and you're not revealing information that limits the options within q, there's no useful disclosure, as the most effective attack is still brute-force over q.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are more than q choices for the polynomial underlying the product sharing, but couldn't there still be a bias on the constant term of these polynomials so some values of ak are more likely than others?